# How preserve the values accessing dynamic controls

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hello everybody and thanks in advance,

I´ve read several threads about but I'm very confused. The thing is I'm dynamically creating some textboxes inside a panel control which is placed inside a formview whith this code...

```
    protected void Muestra_Precio_Stock_BT_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBoxList FormatosCL = (CheckBoxList)FormViewDiscos.FindControl("FormatosCL");
        Panel Precio_Stock_PN = (Panel)FormViewDiscos.FindControl("CB_Precio_Stock_PN");

        Label NuevoPrecioLB = null;
        TextBox NuevoPrecioTB = null;
        Label NuevoStockLB = null;
        TextBox NuevoStockTB = null;

        foreach (ListItem item in FormatosCL.Items)
        {
            if(item.Selected)
            {
                NuevoPrecioLB = new Label();
                NuevoPrecioTB = new TextBox();
                NuevoStockLB = new Label();
                NuevoStockTB = new TextBox();

                NuevoPrecioLB.ID = "NuevoPrecioLB_" + FormatosCL.Items.IndexOf(item);
                NuevoPrecioLB.Text = "PRECIO " + item.Text + ": ";
                NuevoPrecioTB.ID = "NuevoPrecioTB_" + FormatosCL.Items.IndexOf(item);

                NuevoStockLB.ID = "NuevoStockLB_" + FormatosCL.Items.IndexOf(item);
                NuevoStockLB.Text = " STOCK " + item.Text + ": ";
                NuevoStockTB.ID = "NuevoStockTB_" + FormatosCL.Items.IndexOf(item);

                Precio_Stock_PN.Controls.Add(NuevoPrecioLB);
                Precio_Stock_PN.Controls.Add(NuevoPrecioTB);
                Precio_Stock_PN.Controls.Add(NuevoStockLB);
                Precio_Stock_PN.Controls.Add(NuevoStockTB);

                Precio_Stock_PN.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));
            }
        }
    }
```

Well, this works well, when I run the project the textboxes and labels are created as expected, I can see them and write into the textboxes. I`ve put the same code into Page_Load event and now I can get the created controls and avoid the nullpointerexception (that was my first problem) when I click the INSERT button of the formview. The problem is that, in the following code...

```
    protected void InsertButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox DiscIdTB = (TextBox)FormViewDiscos.FindControl("DiscIdTB");
        TextBox CaratulaTB = (TextBox)FormViewDiscos.FindControl("CaratulaTB");
        CheckBoxList CancionesCL = (CheckBoxList)FormViewDiscos.FindControl("CancionesCL");
        CheckBoxList FormatosCL = (CheckBoxList)FormViewDiscos.FindControl("FormatosCL");

        using (SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConexionBBDD-Discos"].ConnectionString))
        {
            conexion.Open();

            cmd.Connection = conexion;

            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO DISCOS_FORMATOS (ID_DISCO, ID_FORMATO, PRECIO, STOCK) VALUES ((SELECT MAX(ID_DISCO) FROM DISCOS), @IdFormato, 0, 0)";

            foreach (ListItem item in FormatosCL.Items)
            {
                if (item.Selected)
                {
                    Panel Precio_Stock_PN = (Panel)FormViewDiscos.FindControl("CB_Precio_Stock_PN");

                    string control = "NuevoPrecioTB_" + (FormatosCL.Items.IndexOf(item));
                    string control2 = "NuevoStockTB_" + (FormatosCL.Items.IndexOf(item));

                    TextBox Precio = (TextBox)Precio_Stock_PN.FindControl(control);
                    TextBox Stock = (TextBox)Precio_Stock_PN.FindControl(control2);

                    cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdFormato", item.Value);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdPrecio", Convert.ToInt32(Precio.Text));
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdStock", Convert.ToInt32(Stock.Text));

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                }

            }

            conexion.Close();
            cmd.Dispose();
        }

    }
```

when the execution reaches these lines, dynamically created textboxes lost their values, returning always 0...

```
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdPrecio", Convert.ToInt32(Precio.Text));
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdStock", Convert.ToInt32(Stock.Text));
```

How can I preserve their user typed values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried putting the code in the Page_Load method inside a block with

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    //
}
```

Another thing you can try if this doesn't work is saving the typed-in values in Session variables.

I don't think the InsertButton is important here. By the way, if you use the runat=server on the objects you don't have to use FindControl, the server will be able to manage it.  Also for dynamic controls you might want to try a different approach like: GridView (remove headers and it won't look like a grid), a DataList, or a ListView. What goes inside the ItemTemplate are the objects you are repeating/creating dynamically.  You can add labels and textboxes here.  For example:

```
<asp:ListView ID="repeatedStuff" runat="server"><ItemTemplate>                                                 
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Or

```
<asp:DataListID="list"
CellPadding="2"
RepeatDirection="Vertical"
RepeatLayout="Table"
RepeatColumns="2"
runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>

<asp:CheckBoxID="cboxP"AutoPostBack="True"runat="server"/>
<asp:Labelrunat="server"Text='<%#Bind("Nombre")%>'ID='<%#Bind("ID")%>'></asp:Label>

</ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

What remains after this approach is managing the binding and how to identify them when an event is triggered.  Like adding a textchange event on server side, if you bind the ID value on the event you ask for the sender's ID and then you can know which one is being "textchanged".

Comment: Thanks for your answer Fenrir88. I've put the Muestra_Precio_Stock_BT_Click code, that is the one who creates the controls, in the Page_Load as you especified, but still values are 0, did you mean the code of InsertButton_Click?

Comment: Hmm...  ok to be sure about this maybe you could share the Page_Load event code.  If I understand the code correctly, when the Muestra_Precio_Stock button is clicked, you are assigning Null to the labels and textbox (which will delete data within them). Then if an item is selected you create them again and add them the text of the selected item.  Is this correct?

Comment: Ok Fenrir88, it's solved thanks to a couple of clues you gave me, like putting the code inside Load_Page event and removing null assigments for the controls, hummm, well, and a, let's call it "a minor detail"... If you pay attention at the end of my INSERT statement, well... I WAS PASSING 0s LITERALLY INSTEAD OF THE TEXTBOXES VALUES" :-O, it was my fault, sorry. But as I said before, your clues were essentials, so thank you again.